# Setting attribute values of XML using Python's Etree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to modify XML using Python's Etree Module. I am trying to look through a fairly complicated XML for a 'ScanItem'. The children of ScanItem has three keys (['name', 'type', 'value']). I am looking to modify the contents of 'value'.

Here is my code so far:

```
from lxml import etree

model_dir = 'D:\MPhil\Model_Building\Models\Retinoic_acid\[07]\Model_LIne_10'
model_name = 'M28.cps'
model_file=os.path.join(model_dir,model_name) #model_file contains the XML

IA=Identifiability_Analysis() # custom class
copasiML_str= IA.read_copasiML_as_string(model_file)
copasiML=etree.fromstring(copasiML_str) # parse XML with etree
parameters_dict=IA.extract_parameters_to_dict(model_file) #extract some parameters from the XML
reaction_name_i='v1'
parameter_name_i='Kcat'
maxi = float(parameters_dict[reaction_name_i][parameter_name_i])*2 #calculating changes
mini = float(parameters_dict[reaction_name_i][parameter_name_i])/2 # calculating changes

query = "//*[@name='ScanItem']"  #looks for the element called ScanItem
for j in copasiML_i.xpath(query):
    children = list(j) #gets the children of ScanItem
    for k in children:
        if k.attrib['name']=='Maximum': #finds the 'bit' that I want to change
            copasiML_i.set(k.attrib['value'],maxi) #an attempt at changing the value to maxi. This does not work
```

This last line gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid attribute name u'0.0102086'  #which is the value of 'maxi'
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out in the end. 
Its a simple assignment with the same syntax as a normal Python dictionary